# Phonegap parameterized table creation

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to create a function that dynamically inserts data into a table:
So far I have tried:

however,when I execute this code, nothing happens ie. no alert. If I comment out the last tx.executesql insertion line ie. the dynamic one everything works fine. How would I have to change that line to make everything work? Please help... Phonegap newbie here.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    var tableName;
    var db;
    var id='14';
    var data='Terry had a little lamb little lamb';

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }

     // Populate the database 
    //
    function populateDB(tx) {
         tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
         tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
         tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
         tx.executeSql(
                'INSERT INTO DEMO (id,data') VALUES (?, ?);',
                [id,data],
                function (transaction, resultSet) {
                 //success code
                 alert('sucessful insertion');
                 },
                 errorCB
            );
    }

    // Transaction error callback
    //
    function errorCB(err) {
        alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
    }

    // Transaction success callback
    //
    function successCB() {
        alert("success!");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a trailing single quote after the word "data":

```
(id,data')
```